# How do I explode a dataframe row for a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, explode

I want to split a string from a cell into a new row just below it.

Right now I use a while loop with an if statement and I iterate over the first column. If it contains the string I'm looking for I use another while loop to append a blank row to the end of the dataframe, and then copy every row down one row until I have a blank row after the one containing the string. Then I copy the string to that blank row.
It feels like the most convoluted way to do this.

I've looked into the explode() function and it seems it should do the trick, but I can't get it to work.

Basically whenever it encounters something like "bla bla (ASTM xxxx)" I want to split out "ASTM xxxx". After I make the column 0 of that new row "Method" and every column after is "ASTM xxxx".

Current working code:

```
var_row = 0
var_row_length = len(df.index)-1
var_countdown = len(df.index)

while var_row < var_row_length:
    if "ASTM" in str(df.iloc[var_row,0]):
        df = df.append(pd.Series(name=var_countdown))
        while var_countdown > var_row:
            df.loc[var_countdown] = df.loc[var_countdown-1]
            var_countdown -= 1
        df.loc[var_countdown+1]=np.nan
        #copy df.iloc[var_countdown,0] to [var_countdown+1,0], copy over to [var_countdown+1,1], keep ASTM xxxx only
        #ffill the rest of the empty row, profit

        df.loc[var_countdown+1,2]=df.loc[var_countdown,0]
        df.loc[var_countdown+1,2] = re.sub('.*ASTM','ASTM',df.loc[var_countdown+1,2])
        df.iloc[var_countdown+1,2]=df.iloc[var_countdown+1,2].replace('):','')
        df.iloc[var_countdown+1,2:] = df.iloc[var_countdown+1,2:].fillna(method='ffill')

        df.iloc[var_countdown,0]=df.iloc[var_countdown,0].split('(')[0]

        df.iloc[var_countdown+1,1]="Method"
        var_countdown = len(df.index)
        var_row += 1
```

I can find the values just using this:

```
df[df[0].str.contains("ASTM", na=False)]
```

But I don't know how to split the 'ASTM' string into another row just below it.

When I use explode() nothing happens. And I don't know if I can even explode it on a chosen string. Maybe with split() and explode() together?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this,

```
mask = df[0].str.contains("ASTM", na=False)
df.loc[mask, 6] = df[0]
```

take mask using df[0].str.contains("ASTM", na=False), create new column store only masked values

Comment: I want a new row, not a new column. Won't that code just add the new column at the end too?

Comment: So for every cell in column 0 that contains the string "xxxx" I want to add a new row right after that row. e.g df.iloc[5,0] contains the string "xxxx", I want a new row at df.iloc[6,:]

Comment: @Mitch - I think, my current code fulfills your requirement.

Comment: I think the current code overwrites an existing row. I need it to create a new row and have it inserted in the dataframe.

Comment: @Mitch - can you show your data frame sample and expected output.